# :after :before селекторы, не работает

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/qg9Rj/

```css
#button-cart:before {
    background-color: black;
    content:" ";
    height: 37px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    display:block;
}
#button-cart:after {
    background-color: black;
    content:"*";
    height: 17px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ПОЛОЖИТЬ В КОРЗИНУ" id="button-cart" class="button">
```

Почему не показываются черные блоки по углам?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

селекторы `:before` и `:after` применяется ко всем элементам, но результат не везде даёт.

`:before` и `:after` добавляет контент к содержимому элемента, а у `input` же как такового содержимого нет.

Решение - завернуть инпуты в `div` и к нему уже применять псевдоэлементы.

Comment: Проще говоря - применяется к парным тегам, контейнерам. А к инпутам, картинкам и прочим не применяется. Как применяется я недавно рассказывал: http://hashcode.ru/questions/259313/css-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-html5-%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-after-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-before

Comment: Решение - использовать button так как это контейнер в отличии от input

Comment: Да, совершенно верно

Answer (score 3):

Замени `input` на `button`.

И используй `text-transform: uppercase;` вместо написания текста заглавными буквами.

Comment: Ответ еще тогда был, зачем писать?